# Supported HTTP2 client libraries similar like OKHTTP/Jetty for Java Embedded ME

Tags: java-me, okhttp, http2, jetty-9

We are trying to access server which supports HTTP2 from the Java embedded ME client. I am looking for list of HTTP2 Client library similar to OKHTTP, Jetty for constraint environment like Java Embedded ME. If anybody has done similar thing/samples or suggestion how to send HTTP2 request from Java Embedded ME client to server which supports HTTP2. Please suggest.

We tried with OKHttp for Java ME platform but it requires additional package like java.util.net etc. Also Jetty with HTTP2 has Java 8 dependency if I am not wrong which our embedded device will not support?

Thanks in advance..